# Can I enable Netrw after `vim -u NONE`?

Tags: vim

Can I load netrw after loading Vim with `vim -u NONE`?.

I've considered statements such as

```
:set nocp
:set filetype on
:set filetype plugin on
:let g:loaded_netrw=1
:let g:loaded_netrwPlugin=1
:h netrw-start
```

I realize I could make for instance some `~/.minimal-vimrc-netrw`, but wondering if there's a way to enable "manually".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run

```
runtime plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
```

This will search for the first instance of `plugin/netrwPlugin.vim` in your runtime path and source the file.

Comment: It worked with `:se nocp`, `:so $VIMRUNTIME/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim`, and `:E`. For some reason, `:e.` has always been the last to work for me. It simply states that `"." is a directory`. Oh well, was just trying to optimize my use after `vim -u NONE`. Thank you!

Comment: @BradyTrainor it might be a bug in netrw. You could email the maintainer if you wanted. (Just curious why are you trying to optimize usage in `vim -u NONE` are you going to be using it a lot?)

Comment: I think I was getting ready to empty my `.vimrc` into a `.gvimrc`, and was trying to get a preemptive sense of what I would want in a minimal `.vimrc`. Of course, I did not anticipate/recall that `vim -u NONE` is not so close to a minimal `.vimrc`. I did spend a few moments trying to see how quickly I could make `vim -u NONE` more comfortable, for instance, `:nn ; :` and `;se nocp` are easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

Putting

```
let g:loaded_netrw=1
```

in your .vimrc tells netrw.vim not to load as its been loaded already.  Of course, it hasn't been loaded -- but that statement is telling netrw.vim not to load (ie. finish early).

Likewise, putting

```
let g:loaded_netrwPlugin=1
```

is telling netrwPlugin.vim not to load.

As an alternative,btw, to the runtime call: you may use`so $HOME/.vim/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim` (or use vimfiles if you're on windows). The runtime call uses a search on the runtimepath (which is probably better, but just thought I'd point this out).